# About networking sockets

Tags: sockets

Do I need to have a server to work with sockets?
Can I directly send packets to other client and receive it without neither of the host being a server?

Comment: Server is an entity (hw or sw) that exposes a service. Client is the corresponding entity that requests that service. A machine with a socket accepting request is a server. A machine sending request to that socket is a client. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Even on the very same computer. Just make sure they use the same port and the client tries to connect to localhost. I use this technique on a regular basis to test my networking apps.

Comment: So I could make some direct chat program without having to host a server?

Answer (score 0):

Any two computers may talk, but one must be a server and the other the client.  They can swap roles and each can be the opposite of the other.

Comment: But they can still be regular computers without hosting a server to work as one?

Answer (score 0):

The Client / Server distinction in socket programming isn't as specific as it sounds.  Basically it has to do with the way the two machines connect.

The server uses `bind`, `listen`, and `accept` to constantly wait for incoming connections. The client has to know the IP address of the server.  This is why URLs and DNS exist, to provide an easy-to-remember name that maps to a server's IP address.

Once the client `connect()`s and is `accept()`ed by the server, the differences are pretty much over.  The client and server can both `send()` and `recv()` bytes whenever they want, and there are no restrictions on the data.

Any computer can be a server.  You could have a 386 laptop as a server and a brand new dual-Xeon rack machine as a client.